# Xamarin mSYM hashes don't match with exception stack trace hashes

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mono

I'm attempting to use the mono-symbolicate tool (indirectly via this cool [helper service](https://github.com/kiliman/mono-symbolicate-helper)) to retrieve the line numbers in my release build exception stack traces (which log to HockeyApp.)

I'm pretty sure my release build config has the proper settings for generating the necessary debug symbols:

```
<PropertyGroup Condition=" '$(Configuration)|$(Platform)' == 'Release-Prod|AnyCPU' ">
    <OutputPath>bin\Release</OutputPath>
    <ErrorReport>prompt</ErrorReport>
    <WarningLevel>4</WarningLevel>
    <ConsolePause>false</ConsolePause>
    <AndroidUseSharedRuntime>false</AndroidUseSharedRuntime>
    <AndroidLinkSkip>System.Core;System.Runtime.Serialization;Android.Gms.Gcm</AndroidLinkSkip>
    <AndroidSupportedAbis>armeabi-v7a;arm64-v8a;armeabi;x86;x86_64</AndroidSupportedAbis>
    <JavaMaximumHeapSize>1G</JavaMaximumHeapSize>
    <AndroidLinkMode>SdkOnly</AndroidLinkMode>
    <AndroidEnableMultiDex>true</AndroidEnableMultiDex>
    <MonoSymbolArchive>True</MonoSymbolArchive>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>true</Optimize>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Below is an example exception stack trace, for the release build 349. The code lines relevant to my application have a hash of d69074b01bdc4aee9b338c440e2a3b69. Note that I added spaces around the hashes, otherwise SO is hiding them.

```
android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. 
Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. 
Parameter name: index   
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException(System.ExceptionArgument argument, System.ExceptionResource resource) [0x00029] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    
at System.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentOutOfRangeException () [0x00000] in <896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf>:0    
at RPR.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.PropertyDetails.PropertyDetailsFragmentBundle.UpdateLists() [0x001b4] in < d69074b01bdc4aee9b338c440e2a3b69 >:0    
at RPR.Mobile.Droid.Fragments.PropertyDetails.PropertyDetailsFragment+<>c__DisplayClass9_1.<BuildDataTasks>b__5() [0x00022] in < d69074b01bdc4aee9b338c440e2a3b69 >:0    
at RPR.Mobile.DataServiceStore+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Call>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x00030] in < d69074b01bdc4aee9b338c440e2a3b69 >:0    
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskExtensionsShared+<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<Callbacks>b__0 (System.Threading.Tasks.Task t) [0x0000e] in < d69074b01bdc4aee9b338c440e2a3b69 >:0    
at System.Threading.Tasks.ContinuationTaskFromTask.InnerInvoke () [0x00024] in < 896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf >:0    
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute () [0x00010] in < 896ad1d315ca4ba7b117efb8dacaedcf >:0
```

Release build 349 was archived on August 16, and was the only build archived on that date. (The warning tooltip says that debugging is enabled.)

[image]

When I go to the archive folder for this build, and drill down to the mSYM folders, there is no hash folder that matches d69074b01bdc4aee9b338c440e2a3b69.

[image]

Due to there not being a matching folder, mono-symbolicate fails to populate the line numbers in the exception stack trace. The question is, why don't the hash folders match up with the hashes in the exception stack trace??

Comment: Is this happened when you use a `listView`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The issue isn't about the exception itself, the issue is capturing line numbers in exception stack traces, which can't happen via mono-symbolicate if the hashes don't match up.

Comment: Please refer to : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/f46f9a4f-4f8e-4961-b00b-359065e6b9b8/systemthrowhelperthrowargumentoutofrangeexception?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: I think there is a language barrier, your answer isn't relevant to my question.